# How to touch defines using rspec-puppet?

Tags: tdd, code-coverage, puppet

**Main**

```
define hello::world {
    file { "/tmp/helloworld${name}": }
}
```

**Test**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'hello::world' do
        let(:title) { '0' }

        context 'test' do
                let(:title) { '0' }

                it do
                        should contain_file("/tmp/helloworld0")
                end
        end
end

at_exit { RSpec::Puppet::Coverage.report! }
```

**Outcome**

```
[user@host] sudo rspec
.

Finished in 0.26947 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Total resources:   2
Touched resources: 1
Resource coverage: 50.00%
Untouched resources:

  hello::world[0]
```

Multiple sources i.e. [1](http://rspec-puppet.com/tutorial/), [2](http://genuxation.com/wiki/index.php/RSpec_tests_for_puppet_modules) and [3](http://wikimatze.de/getting-started-with-rspec-puppet/) have been read and

`it { should contain_define('hello::world[0]') }`

or

`it { should contain_class('hello::world[0]') }`

were added, but the issue persists.

**Question**

How to touch defines using rspec-puppet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://rspec-puppet.com/matchers/), you should construct the correct matcher by replacing the colons in the resource type by underscores.

```
it { should contain_hello__world('0') }
```